# Anyone know how to recreate this colour effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, overlay

I've been wondering and wanting to recreate the style below for quite a while. I know the typical overlay options, but overlays that are white would usually simply result in creating a greyscale image. I'm certain I am missing something here, but I just cannot wrap my mind around on how to create something like this - especially with such a light tone. Anyone got any ideas?

[image: Text]

Here's a similar photo from the same scene but with the actors in colour:

[image: Text]

Sorry for the crappy quality of the second one. Seems to have been a badly recorded video.

Comment: Basically the "trick" is to take a photograph where everything actually *is* white. In the top one I bet the actors wear white makeup. Not easy to make any image look like this. There is an exact duplicate on this site I think. I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Black and White ajustment layer, in selected area for each colors (exemple for the skin, you lower the red and yellow a little more to match the others. The trick is to make really good selections.